# Fixed position with perspective

Tags: html, css, parallax

Here's my **[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qrsotzpr/12/)**.

I would like that my `div id="text"` be fixed. But it doesn't work with my code... The problem is that I need to keep all my content in my div `id="wrapper"`. How can I do? If you have another solution for have the parallax effect on my image (only with css), let me know.

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin:0;
}

#text {
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
#intro {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border:3px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

#wrapper {

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border:3px solid cyan;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

}

#wrapper section {

    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background:pink;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:3px solid red;
    transform-style: inherit;
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 100px;

  }

#wrapper section .back {
      width: 300px;

      border:3px solid green;
      transition: transform 1s ease-out;
      height:200px;
      background-position: center center;
      transform: translateZ(-0.6px) scale(1.5); }

.back {
    background-image: url(http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/background-image/background-image-18.jpg); }





#wrapper section .back:hover {

  opacity: 0.5;
  transform:translateZ(-0.4px) scale(2.6); }
```

Comment: do you need this?: https://jsfiddle.net/4j8gmp0q/

Comment: I need all elements be inside the wrapper

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
/*    position:static;*/
    margin:0;

}

#text {
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#intro {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  border:3px solid yellow;
  position: absolute;
}

#wrapper {

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 1px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border:3px solid cyan;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;

}

#wrapper section {

    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background:pink;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:3px solid red;
    transform-style: inherit;
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 100px;

  }

#wrapper section .back {
      width: 300px;

      border:3px solid green;
      transition: transform 1s ease-out;
      height:200px;
      background-position: center center;
      transform: translateZ(-0.6px) scale(1.5); }

.back {
    background-image: url("http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/background-image/background-image-18.jpg"); }





#wrapper section .back:hover {

  opacity: 0.5;
  transform:translateZ(-0.4px) scale(2.6); }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="intro">
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
  </div>
  <section id="frame1"><div class="back"></div></section>
  <section id="frame3"><div class="back"></div></section>
  <section id="frame5"><div class="back"></div></section>
  <section id="frame7"><div class="back"></div></section>
</div>
<div id="text">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

You need to place the *real* `fixed` element last in DOM (as a sibling of `#wrapper`) and give it `pointer-events:none` so it allows `pointer-events` (including ***scroll***) to pass through to the other `fixed` positioned element (`#wrapper`, which holds the rest of the content) which needs to be scrolled for your parallax effect to happen.

Comment: For my real website, I need all elements be inside the wrapper.

Comment: Andrei Gheorghiu, thanks, it's clear. ;) So the solution is I need to find another solution for my parallax effect...

Comment: You really don't need `position:fixed` on your entire contents. [Read this](https://medium.com/@dhg/parallax-done-right-82ced812e61c#.lbpefyvys) for a good article featuring an example of multiple chained parallax containers, all with `position:fixed`. I assume that's what you're looking for.